# How to keep file in one remote repository but not the other

Tags: git, aws-codecommit

Is that possible to keep one file in one remote repository but not the other?

I am using codecommit to deploy on aws elastic beanstalk, some of the config file should only be on prod environment but not on the dev environment. I try to git rm file and then push to dev. After that, I add the file into .gitignore and push to prod. But the file is also being remove in prod env.

Comment: managing what files get pulled to which environment should be rather a build step configuration task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would solve it.

We externalize configuration and maintained in a separate repository. During deployment, we pull the respective configuration and deploy with them. This also solves the issue of only configuration changes and no code changes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am using eb cli to deploy the code, but it always package the whole repository and replace everything on the server. Any idea how to maintain the separate repository.

Comment: You should be able to deploy by branch codecommit/repository-name/branch-name  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html  when you merge from dev to production branch, replace the configuration update with respective environment.

Comment: So I still need to update the configuration manually every time I merge from dev to prod. Is there any way I can just keep the file on the codecommit repository and don't need to update it every time.

Comment: That file is already tracked, so you cannot ignore it. We do manually update the config on the merge.